# In a Google Sheets spreadsheet, how can QUERY be used on an in memory TRANSPOSE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet 'Results' with data that needs to be transposed in order to query it. I only have read-only access to this sheet so changing it is not possible. I'm currently using an intermediate sheet to hold the transposed 'Results' sheet and querying that...

`=QUERY('Results_Transposed'!A1:AP200, "SELECT H WHERE J >= 0")`

... but I would like to remove the need for this intermediate sheet. However this ...

`=QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Results'!A1:AP200), "SELECT H WHERE J >= 0")`

... doesn't work. This is the error: "*Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: H*".

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or will I have to keep the intermediate sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Results'!A1:AP200), "SELECT Col8 WHERE Col10 >= 0", 0)
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of the ColX notation. It's completely idiotic that Col8 works but H doesn't... but it works so it will have to do!

Comment: QUERY() uses the column letters when reference a range in the sheet. However, when referencing  anything other, we use Col1, Col2, etc. This can be from IMPORTRANGE() or any other function that returns an array.